# What is the probability of exactly one negative solution in a Fibonacci system of equations?

Tags: probability, systems-of-equations, recreational-mathematics, matrix-equations, fibonacci-numbers

The *Fibonacci numbers* denoted by $F_i$ for $i\ge1$ are $$1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,\cdots$$ where they satisfy the property $F_{i+2}=F_{i+1}+F_i$.

I have listed the first $15$ numbers of the sequence as they will be useful for reference later.

Now define $\theta_i$ as the concatenation of $1.F_i$ so that $1<\theta_i<2$.

So for example, $$\theta_1=1.1,\quad\theta_6=1.13,\quad\theta_{15}=1.987.$$

Next, consider the following $3\times3$ system of equations: $$\begin{bmatrix}\theta_i&\theta_{i+1}&\theta_{i+2}\\\theta_{i+4}&\theta_{i+5}&\theta_{i+6}\\\theta_{i+8}&\theta_{i+9}&\theta_{i+10}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}X\\Y\\Z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\theta_{i+3}\\\theta_{i+7}\\\theta_{i+11}\end{bmatrix}$$ from which we can solve for $[X\quad Y\quad Z]^T$ but of course this would be very tedious.

When $i=1,2$, both $X$ and $Y$ are negative but $Z$ is positive. When $i=3$, the opposite occurs.

> **Question:** For $i\le n$, what is the probability that exactly one of $X,Y,Z$ will be negative?

Comment: Isn't the sequence $1,1,2,\cdots $ ?

Comment: Dang @TheSimpliFire doesn't know something? I didn't know such a thing was possible.

Comment: @taritgoswami Conventionally, but in this question I have omitted the first term to avoid duplication.

Comment: @taritgoswami It doesn't change the fundamentals of the problem, just an off by 1 shift. Focus on the problem instead

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I wrote some code to check a few examples...there's a problem with this question. A lot of the systems constructed in this way have dependent equations and hence don't have unique solutions.

Comment: @RushabhMehta That shouldn't happen, considering how sparse $F_i$ are and the decimals. But it would be very interesting to see the code you've produced.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Well, it does rather frequently. For example, see [this](http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi?cmd=li;vdat=3;vdat=R3;m1_1=2;m2_1=3;m3_1=5;m1_2=13;m2_2=21;m3_2=34;m1_3=89;m2_3=144;m3_3=233;curn=3;curn=3;submit21=Submit&hideops=0) or [this](http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi?cmd=li;vdat=3;vdat=R3;m1_1=2;m2_1=13;m3_1=89;m1_2=3;m2_2=21;m3_2=144;m1_3=5;m2_3=34;m3_3=233;curn=3;curn=3;submit21=Submit&hideops=0)

Comment: @RushabhMehta Ah, but watch! This time it's $1.2,1.3,1.13$ etc, not just $2,3,13$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I'm an idiot. wow. hahahaha

Comment: @RushabhMehta Would you mind sharing your code (preferably as a link in the comments)? I'd like to see why dependent matrices are outputted. As that should not be the case.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire see [here](https://tio.run/##RVBLbsMgEF2bU4zSDSiOZZKsrPgAPYPFgtY4HokAApzGp3cHV203gOb95hHWPHt32TZ8BB8zuOURVtAJXGAWehhkfVZs8hEQ0EHU7m64bNtWdKyyjQ7BuJGn5cHtcDp3Sogf2WS9zvwgm8Mx5chRCPgzsYohcVoWTSpcxb5mtAbwKM83axy3xfxFkAuNjlGvZI5dgZVoSDTrYDi/1FdKq0JElymAVThBUQ/4H0UGFp229yZ5@zT8NXR1d5KqLg@6BZAIb60SfS8ptCL331K75bGX7O19gtUvoMcRJGQPeTZgddp/68NE2FcwY02AznDHJ/UqgsJDeGq7mH0lqvk5l2mkeQLt6EyLabbtGw)

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Thoughts?

Comment: One big problem is that it is difficult to give an explicit formula for $\theta_i$ since the number of digits in $F_i$ depends on the integer part of $i\log_{10}((1+\sqrt{5})/2)$.

Comment: @martycohen Using Python, the following proportions are obtained: $$\text{one neg}=0.30443\quad\text{two neg}=0.46808\quad\text{three neg}=0.22748$$ For further information/discussion, feel free to take a look at [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46757158#46757158)